# Best way to save parsed XML in a ArrayList to Local

Tags: android, xml, web-services, listview, arraylist

I am calling a web service that is returning XML and I have parsed the response with XMLPullParser. I then am creating a ArrayList and passing that to my listView. What I am trying to do is save this locally as the web service is very slow. I am not sure if I can use SharedPreferences as the response is strings. Problems I am having the most is people are passing a List or an ArrayList but my array list is tied to my bean class for parsing with the XMLPullParser. I have tried using a LocalDB but I have been having troubles passing my ArrayList to it.

Posting my web service call as I want to save the data before passing it to the ListViews as I need to just take the first record from it and populate 1 listview, then the rest I want to show in the second list. Figured doing that would be easier to do if I can save this data.

```
public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);
                Log.i("AfterParse ", employees.toString());
                mEmployees.clear();
                mEmployees.addAll(employees);

                //want to save the data here if possible

                //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTopListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mBottomListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mMangerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The ArrayList has a response of 
[Employee [Associate = null, Location_name = null, Preferred_first_name = null, PictureURL = null]]

Have tried to add employee to shared preferences after implementing Serializable to my Employee class. I am getting an error that I need to pass a Set and I am passing Set I am not sure if I can convert that to a Set to be able to use.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.one_team_shared), 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

                Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.addAll(employees);
                editor.putStringSet("myKey", set);
                editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your Employee class serializable and store in in SharedPreferences (as XML or JSON)

OR you could try something like this:

```
void saveToCache(String responseBody) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.one_team_shared), 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putString("cache", responseBody).commit();
}

//return empty list if cache is not available
void List<Employee> getFromCache() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.one_team_shared), 0);

    String cachedResponse = sharedPref.getString("cache", "");
    if(cachedResponse.equals("") {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedResponse.getBytes());
    XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
    List<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);
    return employees;
}
```

call saveToCache(String) after you received response from backend, and call getFromCache() anytime you need cached data. It's the simplest solution I can think of.

Comment: You are a life saver, onto the next part. Thank you. I did have to call the getFromCache method from the runOnUiThread.